# flex-direction column property is not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `ul` tag with `display: flex`.

I need it ordered by column with `flex-direction: column;`, but it does not work.

CSS for the container:

```css
#nav li.four_columns ul.sub-menu {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

CSS for the child:

```css
#nav li.four_columns ul.sub-menu li {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */
  /* border-bottom: none; */
}
```

Comment: Change `flex-flow: wrap;` to `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for your reply.
I chaged `flex-flow: wrap;` to `flex-wrap: wrap;` and I only got one column but I need 4 columns.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the source of your problem: `flex-flow: wrap`

This is a shorthand property for `flex-direction` and/or `flex-wrap`.

The initial values of this property are `row nowrap`.

You have only declared the `flex-wrap` component: `wrap`.

This means that the `flex-direction` component remains the default value: `row`.

Hence, your flex items are aligning horizontally in a row that wraps.

**As a solution,** either specify both components:

```
flex-flow: column wrap
```

OR, since you already have `flex-direction: column` in the rule, remove `flex-flow` and use:

```
flex-wrap: wrap
```

**Also important**: If you want flex items to wrap in column-direction, you need to define a height on the container. Without a fixed height, the flex items don't know where to wrap and they'll stay in a single column, expanding the container as necessary.

Reference:

- [5.3. Flex Direction and Wrap: the `flex-flow` shorthand](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-flow-property)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It makes sense but now I only have one column and I need 4.
Could you please tell me how to split the content over several columns ?

Comment: Try something like this on the submenu container: `height: 375px`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michale_B I added a max-height rule.

Answer (score 0):

If flex direction column is not working, make sure you didn't forget to specify the height:

Example:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
    width: 200px;
    /* height: 200px;*/
    flex: 1;
}

#child1 {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 2;
}

#child2 {
    background-color: green;
}

#child3 {
    background-color: blue;
}

<section id="container">
    <div id="child1" class="child"></div>
    <div id="child2" class="child"></div>
    <div id="child3" class="child"></div>
</section>
```