# Flexbox conundrum

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get two containers to sit side by side when media query is applied and cannot seem to achieve that goal. This is a simple header with three columns and a footer. The goal is to have both Nav and Aside on the same row side by side. Whilst I can get the two row reduced in size I cannot get it to wrap.
Many thanks in advance

```css
body {
  font: 24px Helvetica;
  background: #999999;
}
#main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
#main > article {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccc33;
  border-radius: 7pt;
  background: #dddd88;
  flex: 3 1 60%;
  order: 2;
}
#main > nav {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #8888bb;
  border-radius: 7pt;
  background: #ccccff;
  flex: 1 6 20%;
  order: 1;
}
#main > aside {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #8888bb;
  border-radius: 7pt;
  background: #ccccff;
  flex: 1 6 20%;
  order: 3;
}
header,
footer {
  display: block;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #eebb55;
  border-radius: 7pt;
  background: #ffeebb;
}
/* Too narrow to support three columns */

@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
  #main,
  #page {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #main > aside,
  #main > nav {
    width: 47%;
    order: 1;
  }
  #main > nav,
  #main > aside,
  header,
  footer {
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <div id='main'>
    <article>article</article>
    <nav>nav</nav>
    <aside>aside</aside>
  </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you give us some HTML too please :-)

Comment: HTML and CSS are all in the one set of code

Comment: All I see is CSS and a CSS media query

Comment: `#main { flex-flow: row wrap; }` // explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38133968/3597276

Comment: Thought best to offer some visual aid https://jsfiddle.net/Mac_Man/macezk7j/

Comment: flex-flow: row wrap; leaves a huge gap between the wrap Nav - Aside and Article

Comment: Resolved the problem by setting min-height: auto; as all three columns retain the same height based on the longest column. Michael_B provided the solution and many thanks to Michael_B.

Comment: Just about to post the revised fiddle. Not sure how you want to handle the `min-height: 100vh`, but the wrapping is done: https://jsfiddle.net/macezk7j/2/

Answer (score 0):

`flex-direction: column;` was not nessisary once I added `flex-flow: row wrap;` and `min-height: auto;`

You'll notice I also gave the `<article>` tag a `min-height` just so the page still looked ok.

```css
body {
  font: 24px Helvetica;
  background: #999999;
}
#main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
#main > article {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccc33;
  border-radius: 7pt;
  background: #dddd88;
  flex: 3 1 60%;
  order: 2;
}
#main > nav {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #8888bb;
  border-radius: 7pt;
  background: #ccccff;
  flex: 1 6 20%;
  order: 1;
}
#main > aside {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #8888bb;
  border-radius: 7pt;
  background: #ccccff;
  flex: 1 6 20%;
  order: 3;
}
header,
footer {
  display: block;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #eebb55;
  border-radius: 7pt;
  background: #ffeebb;
}
/* Too narrow to support three columns */

@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
  #main {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    min-height: auto;
  }
  #main > aside,
  #main > nav {
    order: 1;
    width: 47%;
  }
  #main > nav,
  #main > aside,
  header,
  footer {
    min-height: 50px;
  }
  #main > article {
    min-height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <div id='main'>
    <article>article</article>
    <nav>nav</nav>
    <aside>aside</aside>
  </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

Hopefully, it's what you're looking for.