# How can I wrap flex horizontally using column inside a grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I'm trying to create overflow flex div with horizontal scroll inside a grid.
In the following codepen you can find a working example on the left of a grid containing a flex div with vertical scroll, and I want to create the exact replica with horizontal scroll.
I have created a mirror of it on the right, but it doesn't work, as it seems that somehow the flex grid width is ignored and overridden by the grid column.

Requirements:
Children's width and height are based on the element content (i.e, max-content)
Scroll in only a single direction
Dynamic sizing for the containers (flex and grid).

I'm attaching 2 pictures that describe the desired results and a codepen experiment.

https://codepen.io/itaied246/pen/eYbOWjm

```
.grid
.flex
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to set a height on your flex box. In this case simply adding `height: 400px` to the .flex-columns class would do the trick.

The reason for this is that your flex box assumes it can be as tall as possible and because the flex direction is set to column it's fitting all the contents into one column. It's easier to visualise when the flex box is a row!

Comment: It's not a good idea because I can't tell the height of the flexbox. Moreover, it does work the other way (row) without setting height or width

Comment: You can set the height to 100% and it will fill the parent. Refer to this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133315/flex-direction-column-property-is-not-working